# Read .txt with emoji characters in python

Tags: python-3.x, text, iso-8859-1

I try to read a chat history with smilies in it, but I get the following error:

***UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 38: character maps to***

My code looks like this:

```
file_name = "chat_file.txt"
chat = open(chat_file)
chatText = chat.read() # read data
chat.close()
print(chatText)
```

I am pretty certain that it's because of elements like: ❤

How can I implement the correct Transformation Format // what is the correct file encoding so python can read these elements?

Comment: What version of python (add a tag) and what encoding (edit question)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Never** open text files without specifying their encoding.

Also, use `with` blocks, these automatically call `.close()` so you don't have to.

```
file_name = "chat_file.txt"

with open(chat_file, encoding="utf8") as chat:
    chat_text = chat.read()

print(chat_text)
```

`iso-8859-1` is a legacy encoding, that means it cannot contain emoji. For emoji the text file has to be Unicode. And the most common encoding for Unicode is `UTF-8`.