# Read in certain lines from a .txt file with python

Tags: python, txt

I have a Example.txt file like the following:

```
Fu
ih
✌
te
eirt
a
nq
awi
oq
qu
acisrrtr
qopa
```

My real .txt file is much longer.

Now I want to read in line 2, 5, 8, 11, ... in a list with Python.

I tried to read in every line and take then only the certain lines from the list but the problem is that I can't read in symbols like ✌,  and  (which occur only in line 3, 6, 9, 12, ...).

I tried the following Python code to do this but it didn't work:

```
Column1 = []

pfad = r"C:/Users/.../"

with open(pfad + "Example1.txt", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = '\n')
    for row in reader:
        Column1.append(row[0])
```

I also tried

```
f.readlines()
```

instead of

```
csv.reader
```

but it isn't working neither.

Can someone please help me?

Best regards

Fab_Freak

Comment: how exactly is readlines() not working?

Comment: Because the symbols are charmaps. You need to use a different type of encoding to read the files: ```with open('yourfile.txt', encoding="utf8") as f```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte X in position Y: character maps to <undefined>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233027/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-x-in-position-y-character)

Answer (score 0):

```py
line_numbers = []

With open(“file.txt”, “r”) as f:
    for num in line_numbers:
        data = f.readlines()[num]
```

Comment: Assuming the line_numbers list is not empty, this would result in exactly the same error since the encoding is wrong for the symbols

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can try this like this.

**Convert txt to csv

**Csv to df

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_fwf('path_to_text_file_with_emojis.txt')
df.to_csv('output.csv')

df = pd.read_csv('output.csv')
df.columns =['num','text']
one_string = ' '.join(df['text'].tolist())
print(one_string)
```

output

```
'Fu ih ✌ te eirt a nq awi oq qu acisrrtr qopa'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use encoding="utf8" in the open function, it is gonna work

Comment: see the ansewer in this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53046443/read-txt-with-emoji-characters-in-python

Comment: Thanks, this works. Sometimes it's that easy. Nevertheless I would like to know how to read in only certain lines, because if I would have really large .txt files it would probably be quicker.

Comment: please check this article to read certain lines
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-read-specific-lines-from-a-file-in-python/

if your purpose to get the lines that has emojis or to erase them from the lines then please check the library emoji, you can just install it using pip install emoji

see this sample code

import emoji
file = open("t.txt",encoding='utf8')


for i, line in enumerate(file):
    for ch in line:
        if emoji.is_emoji(ch):
            print(line)